# Flash-like photo gallery large image animation

Tags: jquery, flash, click, photo-gallery

I'm doing photo gallery and like to **enlarge an image when I click on it with some animation** like it's in flash (the picture slowly expands first by x-axis and after by y-axis and the space around the picture dims), that it scales to it's largest possible size to fit in screen, but **it can be any other animation**.

I found some topics about this, but **I don't want to use any 3rd-party plugin** (including flash, drupal...) to do it. Maybe it can be somehow done by jQuery...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are jquery plugins (not plugins like flash) but pure javascript.

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/02/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-stunning-image-zoom-effects.html

Comment: Maybe i'd like some tutorial how to write the code myself (or some example), I know of jQuery plugins, but I'd rather don't use them.

Comment: Ok! Here's a link to tutorail. http://www.script-tutorials.com/jquery-css-tutorial-zooming-image/

Comment: Ok, I downloaded that Zoomimage and (as it is only JS and CSS) ,it might be the answer. But do you what license is it under? (MIT & GPL, or MIT, or GPL)?